# Select label jquery without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to select the label "`Autres méthode de paiement`" by using jQuery:

Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/0dnd6qj4/

```html
<li class="pay-method available-" data-hide="6">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payment" data-pmt="others" data-index="1" data-card-index="" data-card-temp-token="" data-card-type="" data-bound-index="0" data-pay-method="" issecuritycode="" need-change-currency="false" changed-amt-str="" changed-currency="" changed-amount="" channel-fee="" changed-cur-rate="0">
            Autres méthode de paiement
    </label>
    <span class="card-icon">
        <!-- 主渠道逻辑 -->
                    <i class="checkout-payment-wmebank"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="payment-container" style="overflow: visible; display: block;"></div>
    <p class="error-tops">  </p>

    <!-- 绑卡逻辑 -->
    <!-- 绑卡的list -->

</li>
```

Comment: `$('.pay-method label')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`:contains()` pseudo-class**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) in conjunction with the [`label` element/tag selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/):

```js
$("label:contains('Autres méthode de paiement')")
```

If you have some specific data from the `<input>` that is nested inside the `<label>` (such as its `id` or a unique `name` attributes), you could use the [**`:has()` pseudo-class**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```js
$("label:has(input[name='payment'])")
```

Demo below.

```js
console.log('using :contains()', $("label:contains('Autres méthode de paiement')")[0])
console.log('using :has()', $("label:has(input[name='payment'])")[0])
console.log('without jquery',
  [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('label'), function(e) {
    return e.textContent.includes('Autres méthode de paiement');
  })[0]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pay-method available-" data-hide="6">
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="payment" data-pmt="others" data-index="1" data-card-index="" data-card-temp-token="" data-card-type="" data-bound-index="0" data-pay-method="" issecuritycode="" need-change-currency="false" changed-amt-str="" changed-currency="" changed-amount="" channel-fee="" changed-cur-rate="0">
      Autres méthode de paiement
   </label>
   <span class="card-icon">
      <!-- 主渠道逻辑 -->
      <i class="checkout-payment-wmebank"></i>
   </span>
   <div class="payment-container" style="overflow: visible; display: block;"></div>
   <p class="error-tops"> </p>

  <!-- 绑卡逻辑 -->
  <!-- 绑卡的list -->
</li>
```

Comment: may it work something like this : "document.querySelector('label:contains('Autres méthode de paiement'').click();" )"

Comment: No... It requires jQuery, so it would have to be `$("label:contains('Autres méthode de paiement')").click();`

Comment: Without jQuery it would be something like: `[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('label'), function(e) { return e.textContent.includes('Autres méthode de paiement'); })`

Comment: still doesn't want to work :( , usually I use this "document.querySelector('.product-buy-only').click();" and it works but here I couldn't find out.

Comment: Do `document.querySelector('.pay-method label').click();` then, it is the most similar to what you are already trying.

Comment: yes but there are few of them, may I say to ignore two fist "pay-method" ?

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('.pay-method:nth-child(3) label').click();`

Comment: Gimme a minute.

Comment: Acdcjunior Thank you a lot ! I ll go to sleep, It s late for me,i ll check tomorrow morning as soon as I have at least one eyes open.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('.pay-method:nth-child(2) label').click();`

Comment: Oh yes, sure, I just saw your comment. Good night!

Comment: this one worked !!!!!!! ohh yesssss thank you !!! thank you so much !I spend at least 5 hours looking trying everything I know and google tells me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could target it by the nested input.

```
$('input').filter('[name="payment"]').closest('label');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont use label correctly...

```
 <label for= "payment" > Autres méthode de paiement </label>
 <input type="radio" name="payment" data-pmt="others" data-index="1" data-card-index="" data-card-temp-token="" data-card-type="" data-bound-index="0" data-pay-method="" issecuritycode="" need-change-currency="false" changed-amt-str="" changed-currency="" changed-amount="" channel-fee="" changed-cur-rate="0">
```

Then you can access the label like:

```
$("label[for='payment']")
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to select the label with jQuery? No problem. Use the tag selector, like this:

```
$("label")
```

Please check the API for more information:
https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/